# Pandas - remove the label of the column index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
PLEASE_REMOVE  2013  2014  2015
 THIS_IS_EASY
-------------------------------
          Bob     0     3     4
         Mary     2     3     6
```

The years (2013, 2014, 2015) are the column index labels.
The names (Mary, Bob) are the row index labels.

I have somehow managed to get labels for the row indices and column indices.

Using `df.index.names = ['']` I can remove the THIS_IS_EASY bit.

How can I remove the PLEASE_REMOVE bit?

Desired output is:

```
               2013  2014  2015
 -------------------------------
          Bob     0     3     4
         Mary     2     3     6
```

Comment: What's your data source and sample code?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### New answer for pandas 1.x, [submitted by Ian Logie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61312610)

```
df.columns.name = None
```

#### Old Answer from Oct 2018

Simply delete the name of the columns:

```
del df.columns.name
```

Also, note that `df.index.names = ['']` is not quite the same as `del df.index.name`.

Comment: This worked, and I switched to the `del df.index.name` which I realise now gave me a more correct solution.

Comment: does this work on multipindex? I get 'AttributeError: name'

Comment: @user-2147482637, use MultiIndex.rename() for that. For example, if df has 2 index levels, you can rename the outermost level (level=0) with: `df.index = df.index.rename('new_level_name', level=0)`

Comment: This seems to have broken in Pandas 1.0.3, [this is now the best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61312610/2098573).

Comment: If you do this still "none" or "NAN" will appear while you visualize your dataframe let's say for example in a jupyter notebook. I've found out from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57738153/5127304) that actually the best way is to put `df.columns.name=''`

Comment: In 1.2.4, df.columns.name throws error. It is df.columns.names and it does not take single value, it expects list like df.columns.names = [None, None] if you have multi header. and to remove index label you have to use temp_df.rename_axis(None, inplace=True) seperatly.

Answer (score 18):

Like this:

```
df = df.rename_axis(None)
```

This will get rid of everything on the top left. you can also do it in place: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html

Comment: Not everything. It will only get rid of "THIS IS EASY" in the example in the original post because of the default. `df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1)` or `df = df.rename_axis(None, axis="columns")` to remove the overall name of the columns, i.e. "PLEASE REMOVE" in the example in the original post.

Answer (score 16):

In Pandas 1.0.3 the following works:

```
df.columns.name = None
```

The 'accepted answer' above, `del df.columns.name`, leads to: 'AttributeError: can't delete attribute'

Comment: In pandas 1.0.3, the accepted answer does not work anymore. @Ian Logie you are right.

Comment: Edited my answer (which was accepted back in October 2018) to reflect this correct way to remove the name of the column index. Thanks @IanLogie!

Answer (score 4):

In Pandas 1.0.3 I have used the following :

```
df.rename_axis(None, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

`columns.name` will not work since poster want to remove the index name

```
df.index.name = None
```