# How to remove the index name in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, data-cleaning

In my dataframe, I get a '2' written over my index column's name.
when I check for the columns name it doesn't show up there but as
df.columns give this as output. I don't know how to remove that '2' from my dataset.
[image]

I have tried removing index name but it hasn't solved my issue.

```
 df.columns ==> Output
     Index(['name', 'census 1981', 'census 1998', 'estimate 2000',
       'calculation 2010', 'annual growth', 'latitude', 'longitude',
       'parent division', 'name variants'],
      dtype='object', name=2)
```

I expect only the index with its name...not including that freaking '2' over it[image]

Comment: A [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53036910/2847330).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**you need change the name of columns, not index!**

```
df.columns.name=''
```

Example to understand it:

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['a']=[1,2,3]
df.columns.name='name column'
df.index.name='name index'
df
```

Output:

```
name column  a
name index  
0            1
1            2
2            3
```

Now doing:

```
df.columns.name=''
```

Output:

```
           a
name index  
0          1
1          2
2          3
```

Comment: I renamed the columns, it solved the issue! Thanks bud!

Comment: Finally solved my problem after search for almost 1 hour. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome @Steve We could use : `df = df.rename_axis(columns='')`  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html

Answer (score 4):

## To modify the DataFrame itself:

```
df.rename_axis(None, inplace=True)
```